# What are the algorithms for fusing time series together

Tags: time-series, trend, forecast-combination

Assume I have multiple time series with the same length and the same range. What are the different algorithm used to fuse the time series together? what techniques would the best to combine them to one?

Consider following data sets:

```
X1= 10  11  13  14 17 21 28 35

X2= 15  16  15  18 17 26 29 37

X3= 21  24  19  11 13 20 25 32
```